# Question about Context Switching in xv6 OS x86

Tags: operating-system, kernel, virtual-memory, stack-memory, context-switch

I'm reading OSTEP for my Operating Systems course, and I have a question from [Chp.6.3](https://pages.cs.wisc.edu/%7Eremzi/OSTEP/cpu-mechanisms.pdf):

> Note that there are two types of register saves/restores that happen
> during this protocol. The first is when the timer interrupt occurs; in this
> case, the user registers of the running process are implicitly saved by the
> hardware, using the kernel stack of that process. The second is when the
> OS decides to switch from A to B; in this case, the kernel registers are explicitly saved by the software (i.e., the OS), but this time into memory in
> the process structure of the process. The latter action moves the system
> from running as if it just trapped into the kernel from A to as if it just
> trapped into the kernel from B.

I don't really understand what's going on in this following text-segment and the associated diagram:

[image: Diagram]

Specifically:

- What is going on with the registers during the context switch? It mentions that there are "kernel registers" and "user registers"? Why are both saved, and why are each of them saved where they are? In class, I learned that the user registers are saved into the associated PCB whenever a context-switch occurs, but this seems to suggest that the user registers are saved into the k-stack and the kernel registers onto the PCB? What is the difference between these and what exactly is going on here? Details are appreciated. I really enjoy this stuff.

To be clear: to me, it seems like there is redundancy here, as from the diagram alone, it seems that user registers are being saved into PCB and k-stack and being restored from both.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It's best to think of this as two completely unrelated types of context switches that have nothing to do with each other:

a) A switch from "user-space context" to "kernel context" (or from "kernel context" back to "user-space context") within the same task. This occurs when any interrupt (IRQ, exception, ...) occurs and when the kernel's API is being called by user-space (or when an interrupt or system call handler returns). In this case (especially for interrupts) there's are no calling conventions, and nothing to say "these registers may be trashed by the callee and the caller is responsible for saving them before making the call if it cares". Worse, for interrupts the "caller" can't even predict when they might occur and simply cannot prepare for them (by saving "known trashed" registers beforehand) at all.

b) A switch from one task's context (that was running kernel code) to another task's context (that will also be running kernel code). In this case there is a calling convention involved; most (all?) calling conventions have "callee preserved" and "callee trashed" registers; and the function that does the actual task switch does not have to save/restore any of the "callee trashed" registers.

Note that an IRQ might cause a switch from "user-space context" to "kernel context", and then immediately after that the kernel's IRQ handler might (or might not) decide to cause a switch from one task's context to another task's context.

Also note that in practice it's necessary to treat these as different and independent things; because (e.g.) an IRQ (including a timer IRQ) can occur that does not cause a task switch, and a task switch can be caused by other code that has nothing to do with the timer IRQ (e.g. a task needing to wait for a mutex to be released, causing kernel to switch to some other task while the previous task waits for the mutex).

> What is going on with the registers during the context switch? It mentions that there are "kernel registers" and "user registers"?

During a switch from "user-space context" to "kernel context" the user-space registers must be stored (so that its possible to restore the "user-space context" when switching from "kernel-space context" back to "user-space context" later).

During a switch from one task's (kernel) context to to another task's (kernel) context the previous task's state (registers, etc) must be stored (so that its possible to restore the previous task's context when switching back to the previous task later).

> In class, I learned that the user registers are saved into the associated PCB whenever a context-switch occurs, but this seems to suggest that the user registers are saved into the k-stack and the kernel registers onto the PCB?

For the switch from "user-space context" to "kernel context", the user-space registers are typically saved on the kernel stack (after the CPU switches from "user-stack" to "kernel-stack"). During the switch from one task's context to another task's context, both tasks' user-space registers are still on each tasks' kernel stack. For where the kernel's registers are saved/restored during a switch from one task to another, it's up to the OS designer - most registers can be saved on the task's kernel stack (and not saved in a PCB structure) and most operating systems do that, but some registers (e.g. stack pointer) can't be saved on the kernel stack (or more specifically, can't be restored from the stack later) and must be stored in some kind of PCB structure; and some operating systems just save everything in a PCB structure.

The problem is that your teachers are probably making the (common) mistake of conflating one type of context switch with a completely different type of context switch; and from that perspective the "one context switch that does everything combined" needs to save both the user-space registers (from one type of context switch) and the kernel-space registers (from the other type of context switch).

Comment: I'm not entirely sure what you mean from kernel context. I believe I understood most of what you said except the part on how the kernel context is necessary to save. Could you please elaborate on that? We only really touched on user registers, and my professor mentioned nothing of kernel registers, or kernel-internal details on how it manages itself (which you call two different contexts within the kernel), which I am interested in but don't understand

Comment: @user129393192: "kernel context" just means "running kernel's code" (as opposed to running normal user-space code), which typically implies running with elevated privileges and able to do things that (less trusted) normal programs are not able to do, which involves special rules to elevate privileges (when changing from normal user-space code to kernel's code) and reduce privileges (when changing from kernel's code to normal code); which ends up being a whole protection mechanism built directly into the CPU's hardware (e.g. possibly a dedicated "supervisor mode").

Comment: Right. But why does the kernel need different "contexts" for each user code? I'll be more clear: I've corresponded "context" with a "process's context" and I thought kernel is not a process, so it doesn't have a "context", but manages the "context" of others.

Comment: @user129393192: That's where things get tricky, in a "beyond the textbooks" way. Technically, there's no reason for a kernel to need a different context for each task; it's merely the most common and easiest way to implement a kernel that allows itself to be pre-empted (note: imagine if a task asks the kernel to do something a little expensive, like allocate lots of memory. What happens if the task's time slice ends while the kernel is doing this? "Kernel pre-emption" means the kernel still switches to a different task when the kernel itself is in the middle of doing something)

Comment: @user129393192: There are essentially 2 alternatives. The first is to simply not support kernel pre-emption; which (in real systems) causes unwanted latency, which can be mitigated a little by ensuring the kernel is only capable of doing small fast things (which isn't so hard for a micro-kernel, but is almost impossible for a monolithic kernel). The second alternative is to have explicit "pre-emption points" scattered throughout the kernel's code.  I'm sure both of these techniques have been used before (but it's not something that an average "OS theory" textbook will describe).

Comment: Got it. This was actually something I was wondering about yesterday with scheduling -- would the kernel ever context-switch on a time that is not a multiple of the timer interrupt (ex. has to go disk) and then would that next process that it switches in only get a partial "time slice"? So when you say the kernel has a different context for each task, you just mean there's "contexts" -- but not processes -- of kernel code running, and it can switch itself between "contexts", much like a process would?

Comment: @user129393192: Ironically; for both of those alternatives you can claim that the kernel runs as a separate task (e.g. and that an IRQ, like the timer IRQ, causes a task switch from a user-space task to the kernel's task, then the kernel can do a task switch back to the same user-space task or back to a different user-space task). This is mostly a matter of perspective - a "glass is half full" vs. "glass is half empty" thing where it's essentially the same thing but described in a different way.

Comment: @user129393192: Whenever a task blocks (waits for disk IO, waits for a network packet, waits to acquire a mutex, waits to receive data from another task, ...) and whenever a task finishes/terminates; a task switch occurs that isn't on a multiple of the timer interrupt. For lots of kernels the same can happen when a task unblocks (e.g. when you press a key, a high priority task might unblock and immediately pre-empt a lower priority task). This is part of the reason it's good to separate task switches from "user <-> kernel" switches.

Comment: So to be totally clear: this method of having "kernel contexts" allows us to have the kernel prioritize the tasks it itself has to do for the "user contexts". I am a bit confused on what you just said though: are you saying that the kernel may start doing the task of another, higher-priority process *during* the time slice of a lower-priority process, just because it unblocked, and this is a "task switch" not on a multiple of the timer interrupt? Wouldn't that create a mess, because then the kernel has to decide which "user task" to run next, and they could run less than a "time quanta"?

Comment: @user129393192: I use "task" to mean "process or thread or whatever it is that the scheduler schedules". If the kernel is designed to allow it; a kernel can switch to another task/thread/process/whatever any time it wants for any reason it feels like (without caring about "time quanta", and possibly without having any concept of "time quanta").

Comment: Got it. So this could possibly mess up scheduling and interrupt timing, so that has to be accounted for? I'm interested in a lot more details about this -- do you know where I could find more info, perhaps more detailed/in-depth textbooks or online posts on it?

Comment: @user129393192: If the kernel uses a fixed frequency timer, typically it runs at a higher frequency (e.g. an IRQ every 1 ms), the timer IRQ handler has its own counter (like `if( ticks_until_task_switch-- == 0) { tell_scheduler_to_do_a_task_switch(); }`), and the counter is set by the scheduler (e.g. set to 10 if the scheduler wants a time slice to end in about 10 ms) while ignoring any rounding because nobody cares if the time slice ends at slightly the wrong time. Most kernels don't use a fixed frequency timer now though - see: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Tickless_kernel

Comment: So what exactly does this mean for our discussion? Are you saying that the frequency would be altered and the "ticks" adjusted based on what is going on with the "task" switches at any point?

Comment: @user129393192: First; most timers have 2 modes: fixed frequency (wait until time passes, generate an IRQ, then reset/repeat that forever) and one-shot (wait until time passes, generate an IRQ, then do nothing until software sets a new delay). The `if( ticks_until_task_switch-- == 0) { tell_scheduler_to_do_a_task_switch(); }` is mostly using a fixed frequency timer to emulate a one-shot timer.

Comment: @user129393192: The benefit of "one shot" is that the scheduler can set any time slice length it feels like each time it does a task switch, including things like "infinite time slice" (if no other task is running anyway), and "task's priority determines how long that task's time slice is". It's also immune to any problems that can occur when a task switch occurs for other reasons (e.g. because the running task blocked or terminated) because any remaining time that task didn't use gets replaced by whatever time the next task will be given.

Comment: For the last case you mentioned, shouldn't the kernel be able to tell via some other method if a given process exits at any point, else a lot of time will be wasted?

Comment: @user129393192: Yes, the kernel definitely knows if a process exits (or crashes, or is killed). The trouble is, if the timer IRQ occurs every 10 ms and the task blocked or terminated when there's 5 ms left, what do you do? Either you give the next task an extra 5 ms (so maybe it gets 15 ms instead of 10 ms) or the next task gets 5 ms less (so maybe it gets 5 ms instead of 10 ms). In a word where everything is nice it's not a huge problem; but in the real world someone will exploit it to repeatedly either boost one of their threads or nerf someone else's thread.

Comment: Right, but that requires knowing the scheduling algorithm, and I thought there's safeguards against gaming? Do you know what usually happens in these cases, that is sort of what I'm curious about, when stuff that isn't on multiples of timer IRQ occurs.

Comment: @user129393192: That's what the "one shot" discussion was for: a process blocks/terminates in the middle of its time slice, the scheduler switches to the next process and tells the timer to generate an IRQ at "`now() + time_slice_length`", and the length of the next process' time slice doesn't depend on how much time the previous process didn't use. This is also the safeguard against gaming. Ironically, most processes block before they consume their whole time slice (causing timer to be changed before the IRQ occurs) so the timer IRQ might never actually happen.

Comment: I've been searching online for a "one shot" timer. Is "one shot" another way to say "tickless?" like the link you linked: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Tickless_kernel ?

Comment: @user129393192: "One shot" is about the actual timer hardware; and can go by different names for different timers. For 80x86 PCs, for the old PIT/8254 it's called "Interrupt on terminal count", for HPET it's called "one shot mode", and for the local APIC timer there's (older) "one shot mode" and (newer, more precise) "TSC deadline mode". "Tickless" is more about how software uses (possibly abstract) timers; but "one shot" hardware is more suited to "tickless" software (and "fixed frequency" hardware is more suited to software designed for a regular tick).